# Debugging a FileQueueError using Swfupload

Tags: swfupload

My swfupload implementation is triggering the fileQueueError function when I try to select multiple files.  When I select one file the upload works as expected.

I'm logging the variables passed to the javascript functions and here's what I get anytime I select more than one file.

fileQueueError 
file : null
errorCode : -100
message : 1

fileDialogComplete

Anyone got suggestions on how to trace the source of the error?

Answer (score 1):

According to the file SWFUpload.js:

```
SWFUpload.QUEUE_ERROR = {   

         QUEUE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED            : -100,
         FILE_EXCEEDS_SIZE_LIMIT         : -110,
         ZERO_BYTE_FILE                  : -120,
         INVALID_FILETYPE                : -130
};


so,QUEUE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
```